# Inserting a value with the result of a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an insert statement being fed from a select statement

```
insert into group_identifiers(Group_ID, val1, val2, ...)

select distinct Group_ID, val1, val2, ... from groups 
    where Group_ID not in 
        (select distinct Group_ID from group_identifiers)

;
```

Which updates the group_identifiers table with any new groups that have been added since the last time it ran. I also have a stored procedure

```
Call group_test(Group_ID)
```

Which returns a count of rows that I'd like to save into the group_identifiers table when the insert occurs.

What I'm not sure of is how to iterate over the select statement to call the stored procedure for each group_id and save/insert the result into the group_identifiers table.

The procedure is time consuming to run, so even though I can iterate over the entire group_identifiers table to update it that way, I'd prefer to manage it so it only runs when needed, i.e. when the data is originally added to the group_identifier table.

Comment: `insert into group_identifiers (...) select group_test(Group_ID) ...` ?

Comment: @Bohemian I thought that only worked with stored functions, not procedures.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks to your comment, I converted it to a function and it works fine, though it seems to take much longer to execute as a function as compared to a procedure.